# TypeScript definition for `gapi.client.storage` not taken into account

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, google-api-js-client

TypeScript tells me that "Property 'storage' does not exist on type 'typeof client'" when calling `gapi.client.storage.buckets.list()`.

This is in the context of a Vue.js application (not sure it matters), I am using the GAPI library.

I have installed the `@types/gapi`, `@types/gapi.auth2`, `@types/gapi.client` and `@types/gapi.client.storage` packages, and TypeScript is correctly recognizing types on calls such as `gapi.load()`, `gapi.client.init()` or `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()`.

However, no matter what I have tried, it always outputs an error on my `gapi.client.storage.buckets.list()` call:

```
ERROR in /Users/olance/Dev/project/src/views/Editor.vue(29,38):
29:38 Property 'storage' does not exist on type 'typeof client'.
    27 |
    28 |   async mounted() {
  > 29 |     this.buckets = await gapi.client.storage.buckets.list({ project: "storage-cloud-editor" });
       |                                      ^
    30 |   }
    31 |
Version: typescript 3.5.3
```

Right now, my `tsconfig.json` file contains the following in `compilerOptions`:

```
"typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "webpack-env", "vuetify", "gapi", "gapi.auth2", "gapi.client.storage", "gapi.client"
    ],
```

By default it was configured with `"types": ["webpack-env"]`, so this is the only way I've been able to make things work, even though the documentation seems to suggest `typeRoots` and `types` would be kind of exclusive.
Removing either or both options makes the compiler fail on other parts of the code (related to vuetify mainly, which does not declare types in `@types`).

What's missing to make TypeScript aware of the `gapi.client.storage` definitions?

Answer (score 0):

While `@types/gapi.client.storage` is the package name, don't reference `gapi.client.storage` when callings its methods. Instead, use `gapi.client.<method name>`.

Using your example above, it would be:

```
gapi.client.buckets.list({ project: "storage-cloud-editor" })
```